# Read a string over serial

Tags: c++, mbed

I want to read a string from an android app onto my board via a Bluetooth (serial) module. The string is determined by a slider and should have values from `-30 to 30`.

Using the MIT app builder, the output type for the variable isn't clear:

[image]

It says `send text`, so I'm assuming this is a string. I want to read this string in my code (using `mbed`).

Using:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

Serial bluetooth (PTC17, PTC16);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); 

void ReadSerial (void);
volatile char Slider;


int main()
{

    bluetooth.baud(38400);
    bluetooth.attach(&ReadSerial);
}    

void ReadSerial()
{
   Slider = bluetooth.getc();
    pc.printf("got string\n");
    pc.printf("string is %c\n", Slider);
}
```

gave me `string is x` or `string is £` or other weird symbols when printing to the serial terminal. [image: Serial Output].

I know there must be conversion going wrong from the string into char, but I'm stuck for a solution.
Why is this happening, and how can I write this string straight into my code?

N.B I also tried using `bluetooth.gets()`, and `printf("", stringname.c_str())` to the same effect.

Comment: While C and C++ do share a common heritage and also have some common syntax, they are still two very different languages. Code that is valid in C might be invalid in C++, and vice-versa. Please only use the language tag of the language you're actually program in (which I guess is C++ from the shown code).

Comment: I would suggest to use Another App from APP store that are already designed to send data over BLE. It will help to find the issue and which module is creating that issue.

Comment: @Vaibhav I know data can be sent using this app software and read using serial - and i'm very sure it outputs as a string as serial.readserial() on arduino works

Comment: @el16a2t and now you are using it with?

Comment: @Vaibhav mbed mate

Comment: Not so sure how the baudrate would matter for Bluetooth.  But 'x' is 01111000 in binary, suggesting that the bits get smeared out due to the baudrate being too low.  115200 might be the next best guess.

Comment: When changing the bluetooth baudrate from 38400 to 115200 the serial output changes from "string is x" or "string is €" to just "string is ." everytime. What might this suggest, changing from the x or € character to a full-stop every time? @HansPassant

Comment: It suggests that the baudrate matters, I can't guess at a better value without knowing what you are supposed to get.  Maybe it is ...